# Looping a range of values to draw rectangles

Tags: python, python-3.x, svg

I am drawing rectangles from a database and I have 8 tuples in row[0], I want to draw each rectangle on its own rather than all at once, is there a way to do an inital loop which draws each rectangle, maybe by me assigning an id rather than using 8 if statements

```
 if row[0]== 1:

   print('<rect   x=',row[1],' y=',row[2],' width=',row[3]-row[1],' height=',row[4]-row[2],' rx="0.2" ry="0.2"></rect>')

 if row[0]== 2:

   print('<rect   x=',row[1],' y=',row[2],' width=',row[3]-row[1],' height=',row[4]-row[2],' rx="0.2" ry="0.2"></rect>')
```

Comment: what a difference between that two print lines?

Comment: @Neil I am drawing from sql with cgi-bin, to show my results in html

Comment: @lloyd If you have have 8 tuples in `row[0]` there is no use in comparing it to a number. Also you are always printing the same rectangle so why the `if`s?

Comment: do you want to draw the rectangles over each other or in different locations?

Comment: @smundlay those rows in the rectangle have different values in them. They will plot out as boxes of rectangular which share boundaries in the same location

Comment: You could use SMIL to cause the rectangles to appear one after the other.